# Couchbase web admin console document filter start key filter

Tags: wildcard, couchbase

I am using the couchbase web admin console. I have some document with the key as jid::xxxx::device, where xxxx is a number. If I want to list all the documents with this key, does the couchbase document filter start key have the wildcard like if I type jid::*::device, the all the document with this pattern can be listed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`startkey` filtering, in CB server 5, is available as CLASSIC EDITOR:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the web UI, but you can do it with the N1QL developer preview.

1. Download DP4 (http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads - scroll down to pre-release) and follow the installation instructions to point cbq-engine to your Couchbase Server address.
2. Run the repl (cbq -engine=http://location-of-cbq-engine) and create a primary index for the bucket, so you can query it (`"CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON <bucket_name>;"`)
3. `"SELECT * FROM <bucket_name> WHERE META(<bucket_name>).id LIKE "jid::%::device";`

This should actually have decent performance even on the developer preview, because you have an index on the document keys.